# LWUIT Blackberry TextField horizontal scroll

Tags: blackberry, java-me, lwuit

I have a problem with LWUIT textfield scroll right issue. I am using it to capture an email from the user and the problem happened when the user enters an email greater than the width of the text field. The text then go down and the user can't see what he write until he finished. I tried setEnableInputScroll to make it scroll right instead of go down but without hope.

[image]

```
    Container username = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    Label emailLabel = new Label("E-mail");
    emailLabel.setPreferredW(120);
    emailLabel.getStyle().setAlignment(Label.RIGHT);
    username.addComponent(emailLabel);
    final TextField email = new TextField(userName);

    email.setLabelForComponent(emailLabel);
    email.setPreferredW(170);

    email.setEnableInputScroll(true);

    username.addComponent(email);
    _form.addComponent(username);
```

Comment: This the link of the screen shot http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/824/scrollproblem.png/

Answer (score 2):

use `email.setSingleLineTextArea(true)` to avoid multiline

Comment: Also make sure you are using 1.5 or newer since I think this issue was fixed for 1.5

Comment: I tried this and download the LWUIT 1.5 version and still have the same problem